# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los archivos de mi web solo estén disponibles desde esta misma?

Tags: apache, apache2

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que el contenido de mi web que está montada en un servidor apache restrinja el acceso o bloquee peticiones desde otros dominios o aplicaciones.

Ejemplo:

Tengo una imagen y me gustaría que la imagen solo se pueda visualizar desde mi dominio web,. Si está incrustada desde otro dominio o IP, que no se muestre y aparezca el error 403.

Comment: Utiliza solo tu localhost. Es decir que no lo publiques en un servidor con acceso a internet.

Comment: Si lo necesito publicar por eso es mi pregunta, pero deseo que solo puedan ver los visitantes entrando desde mi dominio.

Comment: Esto se resuelve usando opciones que eviten el hotlinking.

Comment: hotlinking? no había escuchado muchísimas gracias amigo, voy a investigar

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que las imágenes están en la carpeta `/imagenes`, se puede restringir según el HTTP referrer, y así permitir únicamente cuando no tengan o cuando sea desde tu dominio

Esto es lo que va en el archivo `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$                                          # sin referrer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([-\w.]+\.)?tupagina\.com/ [NC]   # de tu dominio
RewriteRule ^/imagenes(/|$) - [F]
```

> Tenés que cambiar `tupagina\.com` (los puntos van con escape) y `imagenes`.

---

Nota importante: cuando estés realizando pruebas, tené en cuenta que tu navegador seguramente ya tenga las imágenes en caché, por lo que te las va a seguir trayendo cuando estés en otra página. Usá una imagen completamente nueva, agregale un query tipo `img.png?forzar`, o borrá el caché antes de probarlo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sigue permitiendo usarlas en otros sitios, pero ya voy a seguir probando

Comment: @javiermudo algo importante que olvidé mencionar ... muy probablemente el caché del navegador te siga devolviendo esas imágenes.. Probá con una nueva que no hayas probado o eliminando el caché

Comment: funcionó amigo, gracias